# How can an azure function (consumption plan) access a storage account that has public internet access locked down?

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, azure-functions, azure-storage-account

**Use case**

I have an Azure function, on Windows os, running a PowerShell script, that exports sensitive JSON files to a storage account. For production, I want to lock down access to this storage account to a list of users, or IP address.

**Problem**

When I disable all public internet access to the storage account, the Azure function can't write to the storage account:

[image]

Despite it having the connection string to the storage account configured as an environment variable in the function and the system assigned identity, assigned as contributor to the storage account.

Any ideas how I can achieve this with a consumption plan Azure Function? Also, instead of the IP address. Is it possible to allow access to the storage account based on the Azure user accounts only?

Comment: looks like you haven't yet created a virtual network for it

Comment: you would need vnet integration so consumption wont work here, you could use premium plan.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be enough to have a connection string and a system assigned user identity to have access to the storage account.

Comment: In general, from a security point of view. Is it necessary to lock down the storage account and have a premium azure function? 

What I want to do is restrict access to the storage account, so not all users can download the files. 

Is there another approach I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Thomas and @Donny Kwitty

[**`V-NET Integration`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#matrix-of-networking-features) is not possible in Azure Functions Consumption based plan, It is only supported in Azure Functions Premium plan and App service plan.

I created one **`Azure Function App with Premium tier.`**

***Created a VNET add it in the Storage Networking tab and Azure Functions Tab like below:-***

***Azure Storage Networking:-***

[image]

***Azure Function*** **`Vnet-Integration`**:-

[image]

[image]

In my Virtual Network I have added the service endpoint of **`Microsoft.Storage`** to connect to my Storage account:-

[image]

If you do not want to put your Function app and storage inside a VNET, Alternatively you can access your storage account via [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal) by providing your users with Azure storage account reader, Or Azure storage blob data contributor roles OR by using Azure storage [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) with specific permissions embedded in your Function code or saved in Azure Functions configuration settings or Key vault.

Comment: Hi Siddhesh, thanks for the reply. 

Would your alternative solution work for a consumption plan Azure function? Would this approach still expose the storage account publicly to anyone to access? 

"Alternatively you can access your storage account via Azure RBAC by providing your users with Azure storage account reader, Or Azure storage blob data contributor roles OR by using Azure storage SAS token with specific permissions embedded in your Function code or saved in Azure Functions configuration settings or Key vault."

Comment: I have tried an approach: providing access to the storage account via the Azure Function's system assigned identity, and disabling public access to the storage account. 

The result was the azure function was unable to write to the storage account. Is this approach possible only, with public access to the storage account enabled?

Comment: Even if system assigned identity is present in the storage account, The connection will still fail because the public access is disabled, I'd suggest creating a Virtual Network and connecting that VNET and subnet to both Azure Function + storage account given the VNET has Microsoft.Storage service endpoint assigned, Above alternative approach of RBAC and SAS token will work only when the VNET access and Public access is enabled.

Comment: As, The connection of Azure functions travels through Microsoft internal network, There are few IP ranges associated with Storage, That needs to be accessed. When you connect VNET to both the resources, Resources inside the VNET can securely communicate within each other in Azure. Thus, I'll recommending creating a VNET and enabling VNET integration

Comment: Okay, so it's not possible through RBAC and SAS token?

Comment: No It will still travel through Microsoft Backbone network, So you will need to enable either VNET integration or Public access

Comment: Thanks, to be clear. If the storage account has public access, does it mean anyone can access it?

Comment: @Coco No, Not unless you give the Access key, They need some form of authorization in place, Either Access keys, SAS token or RBAC role. Anyone with any of these can access storage account from any browser or computer because of public access. Public access does not directly provide access to your blobs and containers