# How can i give an Azure function app a static ip address?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app in Azure. The Hosting options and plans is Consumption (Serverless).

Now when i go into networking to try and give it a Virtual Network , that option is not enabled , it says Dynamic.

Can this type of function app be allocated a static ip or do i need to go to "Functions Premium" or "App service plan".
Reason i didnt go to these is because i dont have workloads that run continuously, hence Consumption is more suited.

Can i implement static ip in this situation ?

Comment: VNET integration is not supported in Azure Functions Consumption based plan, Refer this Official MS Document- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#matrix-of-networking-features Yes, You will be required to Upgrade your Function App to Premium Tier.

Comment: Refer my SO answer to enable VNET integration in Function App premium plan-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902047/how-can-an-azure-function-consumption-plan-access-a-storage-account-that-has-p/77905628#77905628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SiddheshDesai commented VNET integration is not available when running on a consumption plan.

What you need to do is:

- Create a VNET
- Upgrade your Function App to Premium Tier
- Connect your function app to the VNET
- Create a public IP
- Create a NAT Gateway that uses the public IP Address
- Connect the NAT Gateway to your VNET/subnet

Now all out bound traffic from your VNET/subnet including your app function will use your public IP address

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway